# Android Java - Some of the Buttons have Text Aligned to the Right

Tags: java, android

Some of the `buttons` (2, 4, 6, 8, 0, -, and /) have text aligned to the `right` instead of the `left`. The strange thing is that I have the `textAlignment` properties for all of the buttons that do not have center text set to `center`. Here is my `main_activity.xml`. Sorry if it's a simple mistake, as I am still learning *Android App Development*.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="/"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:text="*"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:text="="
        android:background="#85C2FF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="displayResult"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="+"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="-"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button19"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:text="9"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:text="8"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:text="7"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:text="6"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:text="5"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:text="4"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:text="3"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:text="2"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:text="1"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:text=")"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:text="Cot"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:text="tan"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button17" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:text="sec"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:text="cos"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button18" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:text="csc"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:text="sin"
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button19" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:text="Equation"
        android:background="#ffffcf23"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button26" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:text="Units"
        android:background="#ffffcf23"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button27"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button27" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:text="Matrix"
        android:background="#ffffcf23"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button27"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button27" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button27"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:background="#ff33ff8e"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button23" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button27"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:text="("
        android:background="#FF6600"
        android:onClick="appendCharacter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button19" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your buttons appear to have centered text
 when they have enough space:

[image]

But the buttons on your right side might overlap part of the left side buttons if they don't have enough space.
This happens because you specify the positions from left to right for the left "column" and from right to left for the right "column". When the sum of the wrapped widths is higher than your device width, the overlap occurs.

In order to avoid that kind of issues, I would strongly recommend to use another type of layout like https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html using the weight attribute in order to make it responsive.

Also, with your current implementation, if the device is too wide, you'll have a white space between your columns (a table layout would also fix this).

You might want to check this other question: [Linear Layout for a calculator app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659370/linear-layout-for-a-calculator-app)

Comment: Can you show me an example of the tested code, because it still doesn't work when I remove some of the buttons for space.

Comment: I tested the exact xml you posted. What you see is a preview from Android Studio.